# How to multiply a binary variable to a numeric variable in R

Tags: r, binary, numeric

I am trying to do a glm regression in R. 
However, I am facing a problem with 2 variables. 
I want to know if the distance of a dribble increases shot prediction. 
So when there was no dribble I qualified dribbling distance as zero.

I have the following variables

```
afstand$distance <- as.numeric(afstand$distance)
afstand$angle <- as.numeric(afstand$angle)
afstand$Lay_Off <- factor(afstand$Lay_off, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Cross <- factor(afstand$Cross, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Flick_on <- factor(afstand$Flick_on, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Headed_Pass <- factor(afstand$Headed_Pass, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$High <- factor(afstand$High, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Through_Ball <- factor(afstand$Through_Ball, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Launch <- factor(afstand$Launch, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Long_Ball <- factor(afstand$Long_Ball, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Pull_Back <- factor(afstand$Pull_Back, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Pass <- factor(afstand$Pass, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Shot <- factor(afstand$Shot, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Chipped_Pass <- factor(afstand$Chipped_Pass, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Short_Chipped_Pass <- factor(afstand$Short_Chipped_Pass, levels 
c("0", "1"))
afstand$Dominant <- factor(afstand$Dominant, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Third <- factor(afstand$Third, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Counter <- factor(afstand$Counter, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Turnover <- factor(afstand$Turnover, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Dribble <- factor(afstand$Dribble, levels = c("0", "1"))
afstand$Dribble_Distance <- as.numeric(afstand$Dribble_Distance)
afstand$GameTime <- as.numeric(afstand$GameTime)
afstand$PassRate <- as.numeric(afstand$PassRate)
afstand$Speed <- as.numeric(afstand$Speed)
afstand$Popularity <- as.numeric(afstand$Popularity)
afstand$GameState <- factor(afstand$GameState, levels = 
c("3","1","2","4","5"))




  modelglm6 <- Shot ~ distance + angle + Dribble * Dribble_Distance + 
              Turnover  + Counter + Dominant +
              PassRate + GameState * GameTime + Popularity + Speed + Third
```

Dribble * Dribble distance only seems to go wrong because of singularity

```
Call: glm(formula = modelglm6, family = "binomial", data = trainData)
Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.3889  -0.3321  -0.1303  -0.0604   3.7364  
Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                3.067e+00  2.268e-01  13.521  < 2e-16 ***
distance                  -1.852e-01  4.153e-03 -44.594  < 2e-16 ***
angle                      1.411e+00  1.576e-01   8.955  < 2e-16 ***
Dribble1                   8.097e-01  1.281e-01   6.320 2.62e-10 ***
Dribble_Distance          -2.251e+00  4.712e-01  -4.778 1.77e-06 ***
Turnover1                  1.874e-01  9.974e-02   1.879  0.06022 .  
Counter1                   1.278e-01  6.127e-02   2.086  0.03701 *  
Dominant1                 -1.159e-01  7.158e-02  -1.619  0.10547    
PassRate                  -5.117e-02  3.173e-02  -1.613  0.10677    
GameState1                 1.402e-01  2.624e-01   0.534  0.59324    
GameState2                 9.252e-02  1.410e-01   0.656  0.51173    
GameState4                -4.068e-01  1.462e-01  -2.781  0.00541 ** 
GameState5                -2.822e-01  2.422e-01  -1.165  0.24384    
GameTime                  -1.971e-03  1.290e-03  -1.528  0.12663    
Popularity                -3.007e-01  1.366e-01  -2.201  0.02775 *  
Speed                      1.022e-02  1.349e-02   0.758  0.44838    
Third1                    -1.482e-01  7.470e-02  -1.983  0.04732 *  
Dribble1:Dribble_Distance         NA         NA      NA       NA    
GameState1:GameTime        8.219e-05  3.947e-03   0.021  0.98339    
GameState2:GameTime       -4.695e-03  2.559e-03  -1.835  0.06658 .  
GameState4:GameTime        6.428e-03  2.643e-03   2.432  0.01500 *  
GameState5:GameTime        1.715e-03  3.698e-03   0.464  0.64294
```

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting Dribble just as an integer, since it only takes factor levels of 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks but it keeps the same error @KaleesWaran

Comment: You might have to check this, especially the comments to the answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25804/why-would-r-return-na-as-a-lm-coefficient

Comment: If dribble is a character that you want to encode in an "integer",you need to use `labels` rather than `levels`